# Notation of matrices, conditional elements and rows/columns

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question on how to notate the certain matrices.
Lets say I have a $N\times M$ matrix called $A$.

- What is the notation of the $i$th row of $A$?
- What is the notation of the sum of all elements in $A$ such that each element is larger than $c$?
- What is the notation of the *number* of all elements in $A$ such that each element is larger than $c$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no standard notation for these things, though you can always introduce notation for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think that there is a widely spread commonly accepted notation for these...

You could do it like that:
Let $A=[a_{i,j}]\in \Bbb R^{N\times M}$ and denote by $a_1,\ldots,a_N\in\Bbb R^M$ the rows of $A$.  (this is basically how Horn and Johnson do it in their book [Matrix Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521548233)).

For the rest, let $$S:=\{a_{i,j}\mid 1\leq i \leq N, 1 \leq j \leq M \text{ and } a_{i,j}\geq c\}.$$

and consider 
$$ \gamma = \sum_{x\in S}x \qquad \text{and}\qquad \Gamma = |S|$$
where $|S|$ denotes the cardinality of $S$.

Comment: To denote rows, something like `a_{i,*}` might be OK, too.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, people use also the Matlab notation $a_{i,:}$ and personally I prefer $A=[a_1\ | \ \cdots\ |\ a_M]$ (for the columns and same can be done for the rows). But this is a matter of taste and I don't think there is THE way to do it.